# How to define a type inside a generic interface for a property inside this generic type

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
export interface Column<T> {
    field: string;
    columnFormatter?: (props: {
        value: any/** field type inside T**/; data: T; node: any
    }) => void;
}
```

field is the name of the property inside type T,  how can I say that the value is of that type?

```
export interface IPurchase {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    purchaseDate: Date;
}

let doSomethingWithMyDate: (myDate: Date) => (true);


const columns: Array<Column<IPurchase>> = [
    {
        field: "purchaseDate", /* "purchaseDate" must be inside IPurchase */
        columnFormatter: ({ value /* must identify that this is a Date */ }) => 
            doSomethingWithMyDate(value)

    }];
```

Comment: Maybe you just want `keyof` but the example is pseudo code and you’re not showing a use case so it’s hard to tell.  In any case you presumably want `Column<T>` and not `Column[T]`

Comment: Hmm, is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdAO0m) what you're looking for?  Please test against your use cases and get back to me.  If it's what you need I could write up an answer (or find a relevant dupicate); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, yes I wanted to write <t> but the <pre> </pre> was removing it.
Here the pseudo code: 
shorturl.at/kFILS

Comment: Please put that example directly into the question as plain text (or I could do it for you if you can't figure out how).  If I use my suggested solution like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N91YJN) then does it work for you?  I just want to be sure that my solution meets your needs before writing up an answer

Comment: stackoverflow is complaining that it is not formatted properly when I try do it, do for me please? The answer worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to represent the correlation between the `field` property and the type of the `value` property of the `props` parameter to `columnFormatter`, you need `Column<T>` to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with one member for every key of `T`.  For example, given your `IPurchase` example, you need `Column<IPurchase>` to be

```
type ColumnIPurchase = {
    field: "id";
    columnFormatter?: ((props: {
        value: string;
        data: IPurchase;
        node: any;
    }) => void);
} | {
    field: "name";
    columnFormatter?: ((props: {
        value: string;
        data: IPurchase;
        node: any;
    }) => void) 
} | {
    field: "purchaseDate";
    columnFormatter?: ((props: {
        value: Date;
        data: IPurchase;
        node: any;
    }) => void);
}
```

This will behave as desired:

```
const columns: Array<Column<IPurchase>> = [
    {
        field: "purchaseDate",
        columnFormatter: ({ value }) => doSomethingWithMyDate(value)
    },
    {
        field: "name",
        columnFormatter: ({ value }) => doSomethingWithMyDate(value) // error!
        //  string isn't a Date ----------------------------> ~~~~~ 
    }
];
```

So that's what we want... how can we write `Column<T>` to do it?

---

Here's one way:

```
type Column<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {
    field: K;
    columnFormatter?: (props: { value: T[K]; data: T; node: any }) => void;
} }[keyof T]
```

The general form of this type, `{[K in keyof T]-?: F<K>}[keyof T]`, is known as a *distributive object type*, as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109); we are making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the keys in `keyof T` and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with `keyof T` so as to get a union of `F<K>` for every key `K` in `keyof T`.

In particular here we are computing `{ field: K; columnFormatter?: (props: { value: T[K]; data: T; node: any }) => void; }` where `K` is the type of the key, and `T[K]` is the type of the property value corresponding to that key.

And you can verify that `Column<IPurchase>` evaluates to exactly the desired type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2AeAKgPigXigG8oBtAaSgEs0oBrCEOAMyiwF0BaAfgC5iAsACgooqMyoQEAE37kA3MLFQAxolRoAYnABOKAIbBgEHXygAKMDrhgAzvxIA3fcgj8sFdvKjTD+995ocNJuUPpoIFAAvgCUBHiOcFTSikJR0aQMTKwcwnlCoJCw6ugAkgAKSDoqABb6ttCE8MjoGBVVtfUQOKkA9ABUUIXQzRrt1XUNBIIiYhJSslAARMlLqcpqLVq6BkYmZuaW1nYOSspizq78tsA6NADm6+eivsD+UOOdDU-PQSH84RAP2icXwCSS0hiqXSAB8Zsp5jJ+Es0PoUBA1mdRJsNNo9IZjKZ+IcrDZ7PDnlBLkhQjc7mhHljzq93p9JhBgco-qFAcDYvEqRC4sJYRTRIjFkswB12QARQwY4E49B43aEg5HMmnWbPamheXGTliFn8NldI2ibkAiJ80Hg5JQkVQfq9fIQAAeYF0wGoaEJzH0KmgZqmRCZyWutwewNR6Mj9MZOqg0omXQN+oV0PyCAgPukcAAynB0cAag8AOpUUsAWRA6eJKDrCv46btFluNMdQny+TUaBuqhK-f4AEEdDp9CAMKNWiHunhCKQmWGkwjJEjlimvhB00sADRMjZD1UEkzEpwuGkggX5oslssMys1pvGcx6mJMqIHpMrynideSrGGLfn+yrbPiew6OeVKXtA-Jgj4hbFrmD73E+NS1umb6wXEvS9FAJjWDoACEh5iHhoh0g81C2GgADkPr6FA6ZQJwbHsRxnFcdxeAAH78fxUCfsIXhAA)